# Paypal Integration - Adaptive Pay API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

After gets the preapproval key I'm redirecting my user to approve it within the paypal page: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/br/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=

the problem is that most of my donors are portuguese speakers and the paypal page is opening in english mode.

is it possible to open paypal page in accordance to browser default language?

thanks,
MArcos

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the browser language and set the locale code `eg : country.x=FR`
append it to your redirect URL.

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-8E363396NK9147314&country.x=FR
```